# Table sorter with pager plugin - Events does not bind on other pages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tablesorter, pager

I am working on ASP .Net MVC 3 application. I am using the table sorter plugin along with the pager plugin for loading my list. All my event (I am not using Jquery live but just click event for Edit and Delete button) is working fine in the first page but it is not working in the next page.

Any information on how to resolve this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pager plugin doesn't hide the non-visible table rows, it completely removes them from the table.

So you have two options:

1. Add events to the table using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
2. Try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) and set the [pager plugin](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html) `removeRows` option to `false` - the only problem with using this option is that large tables will sort much slower.

Comment: Thank you so much fudgey :-). I already did the first option. I will definitely take a look at your version.